# cobol "hello world" get error when using visual code with terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin, cobol

So I'm starting to learn COBOL, tried my first "hello world" program, and got an error that I can't solve.

this is the  code:

```
      *hello 
   IDENTIFICATION                      DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.                         HELLO.
   ENVIRONMENT                         DIVISION.                     
   PROCEDURE                           DIVISION.
       DISPLAY 'HELLO'.
       STOP RUN.
```

I'm using vs code with extensions that talk with gnucobol(openCobol), did that with the help of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9M52sAnrOs) video (using windows). When I'm running the code, I get this message:

hello.cbl:1: error: PROGRAM-ID header missing

I've tried to copy the code from a few other sources that have an example code but still got this message.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You likely either don't have the `*` in column 7 (mind possible tabs) or use free format (the use `*>` to denote comments).

Comment: the video looks good - until it starts with "install cygwin"... just get the official windows binaries from https://www.arnoldtrembley.com/GnuCOBOL.htm (download, unpack -> ready)

Comment: ... and for integration with vscode you'd commonly create a launch (and possibly debug) configuration, so you get everything nicely working together (no console needed within vscode).

Comment: Unless you are using free format, IDENTIFICATION needs to start in `area a`, code in `area B` see https://www.tutorialbrain.com/mainframe/cobol_coding_rules/

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to see what your code looks like in a purpose-made IDE for COBOL. Here is a direct copy & paste of your code in OpenCobolIDE:

[image: COBOL format error]

The main issue is the position of the code on lines 2 through 5. COBOL generally will require your code to be very specifically formatted, as you can see from the red lines above, there are limits to where data should exist. This can be changed, but I recommend keeping with it as this may increase your comfort in working with the legacy code that runs the world. Here is an example of how this should be written. I will share both a picture and the code itself so you can see where it is in relation to those red lines.

[image: COBOL formatting]

Code with errors still to show as an example:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. HELLO.
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      *this is a comment
       *this is not a comment
       MAIN-PROCEDURE.
            DISPLAY "Hello world!"
            DISPLAY "This display line is too long, creating the same issue but on the other side"
      *STOP RUN has an error because the above line was cut off inappropriately
            STOP RUN.
       END PROGRAM HELLO.
```

Working code with no errors:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. HELLO.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      *this is a comment
       MAIN-PROCEDURE.
            DISPLAY "Hello world!"
            STOP RUN.
       END PROGRAM HELLO.
```

Definitely check out [OpenCobolIDE](https://pypi.org/project/OpenCobolIDE/) which is a great free IDE for getting started with COBOL and getting the basics down! It helped me to get a better handle on formatting when I was new.